# Problem with triggering action after woocommerce product import

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import, hook

I hope someone could help me :-)
I try to trigger an action after each product imported (via csv file) in a woocommerce shop. Products are variable products with all the same attributes and variations. That's why, to simplify the csv file (just a raw per product), I added a "save_post" action in my theme function.php.
Here is the code :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_add_product_attributes', 50, 3 );
function auto_add_product_attributes( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {

    // Echape la fonction si le post n'est pas de type produit, fonctionne s'il s'agit d'un enregistrement automatique, d'une mise à jour et si l'utilisateur n'est pas autorisé à modifier le produit

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    if( $update )
        return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // convertit le produit en produit variable autorisant les variations et visible en front
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'variable', 'product_type' );
    $visible   = '1';
    $variation = '1';

    // Récupère tous les attributs du menu ATTRIBUTS, crée un tableau vide avec curseur à la postion 0
    global $wpdb;
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" );
    $position   = 0;
    $data       = array();

    // Boucle relative à tous les attributs récupérés
    foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){
        // Récupère noms et ids des attributs
        $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute->attribute_name;
        $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;

        // Récupères les ids des termes de l'attribut courant
        $term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids'));

        // Crée une instance vide de l'objet WC_Product_Attribute
        $product_attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

        // Initialise les données suivantes dans l'objet WC_Product_Attribute
        $product_attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
        $product_attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $product_attribute->set_options( $term_ids );
        $product_attribute->set_position( $position );
        $product_attribute->set_visible( $visible );
        $product_attribute->set_variation( $variation );

        // Ajoute les données de l'objet WC_Product_Attribute dans un tableau et incremente la position
        $data[$taxonomy] = $product_attribute;
        $position++;    
    }
    
    // Récupère les données du produit par son id
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Met à jour les données récupérées par la boucle
    $product->set_attributes( $data );

    // Crée toutes les variations associé aux attributs mis à jour
    wc_maybe_define_constant( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 50 );
    wc_set_time_limit( 0 );
        if ( ! $post_id ) {
            wp_die();
        }
        $data_store = $product->get_data_store();
        if ( ! is_callable( array( $data_store, 'create_all_product_variations' ) ) ) {
            wp_die();
        }
    echo esc_html( $data_store->create_all_product_variations( $product, WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS ) );
    $data_store->sort_all_product_variations( $product->get_id() );

    // sauvegarde le produit
    $product->save(); 

    // Fonction de génération d'un mdp aléatoire
    function generateStrongPassword($length = 9, $add_dashes = false, $available_sets = 'luds')
        {
            $sets = array();
            if(strpos($available_sets, 'l') !== false)
                $sets[] = 'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
            if(strpos($available_sets, 'u') !== false)
                $sets[] = 'ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            if(strpos($available_sets, 'd') !== false)
                $sets[] = '23456789';
            if(strpos($available_sets, 's') !== false)
                $sets[] = '!@#$%&*?';

            $all = '';
            $password = '';
            foreach($sets as $set)
                {
                $password .= $set[array_rand(str_split($set))];
                $all .= $set;
                }

            $all = str_split($all);
            for($i = 0; $i < $length - count($sets); $i++)
                $password .= $all[array_rand($all)];

            $password = str_shuffle($password);

            if(!$add_dashes)
                return $password;

            $dash_len = floor(sqrt($length));
            $dash_str = '';
            while(strlen($password) > $dash_len)
                {
                $dash_str .= substr($password, 0, $dash_len) . '-';
                $password = substr($password, $dash_len);
                }
            $dash_str .= $password;
            return $dash_str;
        }

    //Génère un mdp aléatoire
    $mdp_secure_generated = generateStrongPassword();

    //Tableau stockant les nouvelles valeurs à mettre à jour
    $args_update_mdp = array(
                        'ID'            => $post_id,
                        'post_password' => $mdp_secure_generated,
                        );

    // Mise à jour du mdp
    wp_update_post( $args_update_mdp );

    // Récupère les données du produit par son id
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    foreach( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ){
            //Récupère les data de la variation par son id
            $variation_data = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            //Récupère le nom de cette variation
            $variation_name = $variation_data->get_name();
            // Ote le préfixe composé du nom du produit au nom de la variation
            $chaine_a_oter = $product->get_name()." - ";
            $variation_name = str_replace($chaine_a_oter, "", $variation_name);

            // Récupère descriptions et noms des termes de l'attribut de menu "FORMATS"
            $format_children = get_terms("pa_formats");
            foreach ( $format_children as $term ) {
                    $term_description = get_term_field( 'description', $term );
                    $term_name = get_term_field( 'name', $term );
                    $term_price = get_field( 'prix_en_cours', $term );
                    if ($term_name == $variation_name) {
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_variation_description', $term_description );
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $term_price );
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $term_price );
                    }
            }
            // Vide le cache de la variation
            wc_delete_product_transients( $variation_id );
    }
    // Vide le cache du produit variable
    wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id );

    // sauvegarde le produit
    $product->save();
    
}
```

The first product is correctly imported/created with its attributes/terms/variations/variations values... but import process breaks after import of the second product without running action hook (backend, import process is never completed).
I suspect that the problem occurs when hook runs for the second time... but I don't know where is the issue !
Sorry for my poor english... hope you will understand what I mean :-)
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue with that code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'auto_add_product_attributes', 50, 3 );
function auto_add_product_attributes( $product_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $product_id ;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $product_id ) )
        return $product_id ;


    //Génère un mdp aléatoire
    $mdp_secure_generated = generateStrongPassword();

    //Tableau stockant les nouvelles valeurs à mettre à jour
    $args_update_mdp = array(
                        'ID'            => $product_id,
                        'post_password' => $mdp_secure_generated,
                        );


    // convertit le produit en produit variable autorisant les variations et visible en front
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'variable', 'product_type' );
    $visible   = '1';
    $variation = '1';

    // Récupère tous les attributs du menu ATTRIBUTS, crée un tableau vide avec curseur à la postion 0
    global $wpdb;
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" );
    $position   = 0;
    $data       = array();

    // Boucle relative à tous les attributs récupérés
    foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){
        // Récupère noms et ids des attributs
        $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute->attribute_name;
        $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;

        // Récupères les ids des termes de l'attribut courant
        $term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids'));

        // Crée une instance vide de l'objet WC_Product_Attribute
        $product_attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

        // Initialise les données suivantes dans l'objet WC_Product_Attribute
        $product_attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
        $product_attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $product_attribute->set_options( $term_ids );
        $product_attribute->set_position( $position );
        $product_attribute->set_visible( $visible );
        $product_attribute->set_variation( $variation );

        // Ajoute les données de l'objet WC_Product_Attribute dans un tableau et incremente la position
        $data[$taxonomy] = $product_attribute;
        $position++;    
    }
    
    // Récupère les données du produit par son id
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Mise à jour du mdp
    wp_update_post( $args_update_mdp );

    // Met à jour les données récupérées par la boucle
    $product->set_attributes( $data );

    // Crée toutes les variations associées aux attributs mis à jour
    $data_store = $product->get_data_store();    
    $data_store->create_all_product_variations($product, $maxVariations);
    $data_store->sort_all_product_variations($product->get_id());

    $product->save();

    $product_on = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    foreach( $product_on->get_children() as $variation_id ){
            //Récupère les data de la variation par son id
            $variation_data = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            //Récupère le nom de cette variation
            $variation_name = $variation_data->get_name();
            // Ote le préfixe composé du nom du produit au nom de la variation
            $chaine_a_oter = $product_on->get_name().' - ';
            $variation_name = str_replace($chaine_a_oter, '', $variation_name);

            // Récupère descriptions et noms des termes de l'attribut de menu "FORMATS"
            $format_children = get_terms("pa_formats");
            foreach ( $format_children as $term ) {
                    $term_description = get_term_field( 'description', $term );
                    $term_name = get_term_field( 'name', $term );
                    $term_price = get_field( 'prix_en_cours', $term );
                    if ($term_name == $variation_name) {
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_variation_description', $term_description );
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $term_price );
                        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $term_price );
                    }
            }
            // Vide le cache de la variation
            wc_delete_product_transients( $variation_id );
    }
    // Vide le cache du produit variable
    wc_delete_product_transients( $product_id );

    // sauvegarde le produit
    $product_on->save();
}
```

The problem was the generateStrongPassword() function which was declared twice, and the $product->save() function.
Code tested and works.
Hope it will help :-)